# How do I get the SVN server log?

Tags: svn, server-side

I am trying to find a way to get the SVN **server-side** log, but I only found the way to retrieve the client side logs using `svn:log`. How do I get the server-side logs?

Comment: What type of information you are looking for when you say 'server side log`? `svn log` at the top of repository will tell you everything about repository changes. Are you looking for user maintenance logs?

Comment: I want to know that only administrator group logging information and also in which file these logging information's are available?

Comment: I am looking for admin maintenance logs?

Comment: I don't think that `subversion` keeps the admin maintenance logs. If deployed on UNIX box you can look for logging information there.

Answer (score 14):

For SVN implementations that utilize the `svnserve` executable, it is possible to enable server-side logging by passing the `--log-file` switch when starting the daemon, e.g.:

```
# svnserve -d -r /svn --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log
```

This would cause the `svnserve` daemon to log to the file `/var/log/svnserve.log`.

For the sake of thoroughness, the `-d` switch runs `svnserve` in "Daemon Mode", and the `-r` switch specifies the SVN repository root.

To take my response a step further, it is possible to configure `svnserve` as a service. This ensures that `svnserve` runs on system start-up, and is terminated gracefully on system shutdown.

One method to accomplish this on Debian (and Ubuntu) systems is described at http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/ , and the author provides an `initd` script that should function correctly out-of-the-box: http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/svnserve

For those who employ this script, logging can be enabled by modifying the `DAEMON_ARGS` variable on line 18 (as of this writing) to look something like:

```
DAEMON_ARGS="-d -r /svn --log-file=/var/log/svnserve.log"
```

The service would then be started with

```
# service svnserve start
```

and stopped with

```
# service svnserve stop
```

The script also accepts the `restart` and `force-reload` arguments.